# What is this proposition trying to do?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

**Proposition**

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be permutations in $S(n)$. The cycle decomposition of the element $\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}$ is obtained from that of $\beta$ by replacing each integer $i$ in the cycle decomposition of $\beta$ with the integer $\alpha(i)$.

**Proof**

$\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}(\alpha(i))=\alpha(\beta(i))$

**Example**

Conjugating the permutation $(1,2,3,4,5)$ by $(1,2)(3,4)$, the proposition shows that the result is $(2,1,4,3,5)=(1,4,3,5,2)$. Similarly, the permutation $(1,2)(3,4)$ is conjugate to $(1,3)(2,5)$ via $(2,3)(4,5)$.

**Doubt**

I don't understand anything because I don't know what "*that of $\beta$ by replacing each integer $i$ in the cycle decomposition of $\beta$ with the integer $\alpha(i)$*" means.

It may be because English is not my native language, although I understand it well. I have searched for an explanation in my language (Spanish), but I have not been successful.

I have also read other articles in English (some from this same forum) related to conjugate permutations (I think that is what the topic is about), but without success.

**I understand the following:**

$\alpha=(1,2,3,4,5)$

$\alpha^{-1}=(5,4,3,2,1)$

$\beta=(5,2,4,1,3)$

$\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}=(\alpha(5),\alpha(2),\alpha(4),\alpha(1),\alpha(3))$

Is it correct? Could someone give me a more developed explanation so I can better see the proposition? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You're exactly right! Let's go through a few concrete examples together, and that will probably clarify things.

Let

- $\beta = (1,2,3)(4,5)(6)$
- $\alpha = (3,6)$

Then $\alpha \beta \alpha^{-1} = (1,2,6)(4,5)(3) = (\alpha 1, \alpha 2, \alpha 3)(\alpha 4, \alpha 5)(\alpha 6)$.

Notice $\beta$ and $\alpha \beta \alpha^{-1}$ look *exactly the same*, except we swapped $3$ and $6$. This is because $\alpha$ swaps $3$ and $6$.

Next, let

- $\beta = (1,2,3)(4,5)(6)$
- $\alpha = (2,4)(5,6)$

can you guess what the $\alpha \beta \alpha^{-1}$ will be? I'll put it under a fold:

> $\alpha \beta \alpha^{-1} = (1,4,3)(2,6)(5)$. Because we swap $2$ and $4$, then we swap $5$ and $6$, inside $\beta$.

Now for something a bit harder:

- $\beta = (1,2,3)(4,5)(6)$
- $\alpha = (2,4,6)$

Thankfully, the same idea works!

$$\alpha \beta \alpha^{-1} = (1,4,3)(6,5)(2) = (\alpha 1, \alpha 2, \alpha 3)(\alpha 4, \alpha 5)(\alpha 6)$$

Lastly, let's look at something like

- $\beta = (1,2,3)(4,5)(6)$
- $\alpha = (2,4,6)(1,3)$

Again, you should try this yourself before reading the answer!

> $\alpha \beta \alpha^{-1} = (3,4,1)(6,5)(2)$

And as a little edge case, what about

- $\beta = (1,2,3)(4,5)(6)$
- $\alpha = (4,5)$

> $\alpha \beta \alpha^{-1} = (1,2,3)(5,4)(6)$. Notice this actually *equals* $\beta$ since $(4,5) = (5,4)$! That doesn't matter, though -- the process still works.

If you understand all of this, then it seems to me like you understand the proposition! That's all there is to it.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's clear to me how the calculation is, but then I don't understand the proof.

We have that any $i$ is an image of $\alpha(j)$ for some $j$ and therefore we can take $\alpha(j)$ as an argument, such that $\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}(\alpha(j))=\alpha\beta(j)$. 

Composing $\alpha$ and $\beta$ we get a new permutation. If we prove this with your first example, the result of $\alpha\beta\alpha^{-1}$ is $(1,2,6,3)(4,5)$, not $(1,2,6)(4,5)(3)$.